# How to stop htaccess infinite loop redirection in home page

Tags: prestashop

I want to redirect the home page of my prestashop site based on visitors country to the multishop url which i have created.I have placed the below script in header.tpl file in my template folder to fetch the country code and redirect user to the respective multishop based on his country.

I have created two shops one for users with in my country and another shop as international common to all users.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
var code = location.country_code;
if (code == 'IN')
{
    window.location="http://example.com/in/";
}
else
{
  window.location="http://example.com/international/";
}
 });    
});
</script>
```

During this redirection my site is redirected to the shop based on country code but it keep on redirecting.I have tried several ways to stop the redirection loop but nothing doesn't support me.How to stop this continous redirecting loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current URL is equal (or starts with) the new location.

```
if (code == 'IN' && !window.location.startsWith("http://example.com/in")) {
    window.location="http://example.com/in/";
}
```

Comment: No my current url is not equal to http://example.com/in/. My current index page url is http://example.com/. I am redirecting to else conditon url properly but site keep on loading and its showing connecting and redirecting continously.@newboyhun

Comment: The code was a sample, you can do this for the else too, and change the values ofc.